# Notepad++ Function List for PL/SQL

Tags: notepad++

I'm trying to create a function list for my pl/sql source files. I have spc and bdy files (spec and body for packages).

This is what I defined as associations inside `functionList.xml` (also tried with a "." before the extension):

```
 <association ext="bdy" id="plsql_func"/>
 <association ext="spc" id="plsql_func"/>
```

Now, inside `<parsers>` (at the same level as the other parsers):

```
 <parser id="plsql_func" displayName="PLSQL Function Parser" commentExp="--.*$">
    <function
       mainExpr="^[\t ]*FUNCTION[\t ]*[\w]*\(*"
       displayMode="$functionName">
       <functionName>
          <nameExpr expr="[\w]+\("/>
       </functionName>
    </function>
 </parser>
```

The regular expression `^[\t ]*FUNCTION[\t ]*[\w]*\(*` matches all the function names when I do a search inside a file (no problem there).

I also tried ".*" as the name parser but still, no luck. The function list pane stays empty.

Am I missing something?

ps:

Example function header:

```
FUNCTION TEST_FUNCTION(O_error    VARCHAR2(300),
                       I_args     VARCHAR2(10))
return BOOLEAN IS
```

Answer (score 2):

My pl/sql source file have extension sql so I defined:

```
        <association langID="17" id="plsql_func"/>
```

and improve a litle your parser.

```
        <parser id="plsql_func" displayName="PL/SQL" commentExpr="((/\*.*?\*)/|(--.**$))">
            <function
                mainExpr="^[\t ]*(FUNCTION|PROCEDURE)[\s]*[\w]*[\s]*(\(|IS|AS)*"
                displayMode="$functionName">
                <functionName>
                    <nameExpr expr="[\w]+[\s]*(\(|IS|AS)"/>
                </functionName>
            </function>
        </parser>
```

in my case it work ( notepad++ v6.6.9 )

Comment: Still not working. Also found I  have two functionList.xml files, one in appdata, the other in Program Files. Changed both but still no luck. (Notepad 6.6.9)

Comment: I did it on 6.8.6, not work. So I did a clean install of 6.6.9, it works! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you're using a user defined language for PL-SQL.

Try adding this in your functionList.xml

```
<association userDefinedLangName="PL-SQL" id="plsql_func"/>
```

Where PL-SQL is whatever you call your user defined lanuage.