# Notepad++ Function list for SQL

Tags: plsql, notepad++

quick question .. I'm trying to get the function list option in Notepad++ going ...

Now, I found this thread:
[Notepad++ Function List for PL/SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26412834/notepad-function-list-for-pl-sql)

which helped get me started, however, I'm still struggling with something, and I can't seem to wrap my monkey-brain around it.

It'll be this section I need to focus:

```
        <function
            mainExpr="^[\t ]*(FUNCTION|PROCEDURE)[\s]*[\w]*[\s]*(\(|IS|AS)*"
            displayMode="$functionName">
            <functionName>
                <nameExpr expr="[\w]+[\s]*(\(|IS|AS)"/>
            </functionName>
        </function>
```

That works perfectly fine .. so far.
However, I would like to also see PACKAGE header and PACKAGE BODY names in there as well .. just to help tidy things up.

I figured it'd be easy to tweak the RegExp, however, nothing I've tried is working

So I'm trying to pick out these kinds of scenarios:

```
 CREATE PACKAGE aaa
 CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE bbb
 CREATE PACKAGE BODY ccc
 CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY ddd
```

all 4: aaa, bbb, ccc, and ddd.
I can't even get it to pull back one yet.. :(

Hoping I could get some help/hints/something ..

I know this is the main "logic":

```
mainExpr="^[\t ]*(FUNCTION|PROCEDURE)[\s]*[\w]*[\s]*(\(|IS|AS)*"
```

that finds the line(s) ..

And trying to matchup the logic with what it finds for .. say, FUNCTIONs, and what I want for PACKAGE ... I tried this:

```
mainExpr="^[\t ]*(FUNCTION|PROCEDURE|CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE)[\s]*[\w]*[\s]*(\(|IS|AS)*"
```

but even that doesn't pick out the header! O.o

I'm sure there's something I need to do with the  part .. but again, not really understanding how it works ??

I've read this :
https://notepad-plus-plus.org/features/function-list.html

but there's obviously something about the syntax/usage of this thing I'm not fully understanding ..

hoping somebody can help me out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your problem is coming from the Regex rather than anything you're doing incorrectly. I've made a new parser based on the one I found here: http://www.hermanmol.nl/?p=240

```
<parser id="plsql_func" displayName="PL/SQL" commentExpr="((/\*.*?\*)/|(--.*?$))">
    <function
        mainExpr="^[\w\s]{0,}(PACKAGE BODY|PACKAGE|FUNCTION|PROCEDURE)[\s]{1,}[\w_]{1,}">
        <functionName>
            <nameExpr expr="^[\w\s]{0,}(PACKAGE BODY|PACKAGE|FUNCTION|PROCEDURE)[\s]{1,}\K[\w_]{1,}"/>
        </functionName>
    </function>
</parser>
```

For me this seems to correctly pull out the Package, Procedures and Functions.

One thing to note however, I could not get this to work using a file extension assocation, and used the following instead to test on a text file: `<association langID= "0" id="plsql_func" />`

I also placed the updated functionList.xml file in both the `Program Files (x86)\Notepad++` and the `Users\xxxxx\AppData\Roaming\Notepad++` directories.

Edit - a short explanation of the Regex, I'm not great at Regex but it was requested in the comments

`^[\w\s]{0,}` - From the beginning of the line, find 0 or more letters or white space characters

`(PACKAGE BODY|PACKAGE|FUNCTION|PROCEDURE)` - followed by any of these

`[\s]{1,}[\w_]{1,}` - followed by one or more spaces, followed by one or more words

Comment: ok .. yeah, that's closer ... but I'm also interested in understanding it .. can you explain it a bit ? I'm familiar with regexp . .but no pro . and I'm having trouble "parsing" that myself :)   The issue I'm having now, is my package "names" include schema:  ;)  heh  I'm willing to fix that myself, if I can just understand what you have now and what it's doing.

Comment: oh sweet .. got it :)    `[\w_.]`  just added the period in addition to your _ to include in the "words" .. (i had to look that \w up .. wasn't familiar with it :) )   Thank-you!  (FYI: added the period to both mainExpr and nameExpr .. ) :)

Comment: I'm not great at Regex either, glad it helped though :) I find regexr.com very useful at explaining what is going on

Comment: oh nice .. I trudge through the wikis .. but sometimes my brain just doesn't work :) heh  that regexr.com is nice I gotta book mark that!  :) Thanks Again!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Chrisrs2292,

I was helped by the location of the functionList.xml file in Users\xxxxx\AppData\Roaming\Notepad++ directories.

**RegEX for T-SQL**:

```
<association id= "T-SQL_func" langID="17"/>

<!-- T-SQL-->
<parser displayName="T-SQL" id="T-SQL_func" commentExpr="(?s:/\*.*?\*/)|(?m-s:--.*?$)">
<function mainExpr='(?im)^\h*(create|alter)\s+(function|procedure)\s+((\[|")?[\w_]+(\]|")?\.?)?((\[|")?[\w_]+(\]|")?)?'
          displayMode="$functionName">
    <functionName>
        <nameExpr expr='(?im)(function|procedure)\s+((\[|")?[\w_]+(\]|")?\.?)?((\[|")?[\w_]+(\]|")?)?' />
    </functionName>
</function>
```

Answer (score 0):

Working from what Chrisrs2292 has provided from above, I played around with some PL/SQL code on regex101.com to find a regular expression to find the functions/procedures/etc, and got put that into the functionList.xml.

```
            <parser
                displayName="SQL Node"
                id="sql_node"
                commentExpr="((/\*.*?\*)/|(--.**$))"
            >
            <function
            mainExpr="^[\w\s]+(PACKAGE BODY|PACKAGE|PROCEDURE|FUNCTION)\s+[\w&quot;\.]+"
            >
                <functionName>
                    <nameExpr expr="^[\w\s]+(PACKAGE BODY|PACKAGE|PROCEDURE|FUNCTION)\s+\K[\w&quot;\.]+"/>
                </functionName>
            </function>
            </parser>
```

The big change was I had include the double quotes (using the XML code of ") and dot (the \.) since many times I use the quotes and like to use the fully qualified name (schema.procedure|function|etc). Minor changes are replacing the {0,} with * and {1,} with +. These are minor, cosmetic changes are should be interchangeable.