# Notepad++ FunctionList

Tags: plsql, treeview, notepad++

ok .. I have an odd "followup" to this question:

[Notepad++ Function list for SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42516058/notepad-function-list-for-sql/42551232#42551232)

Got my answer there ... and this question is a bit different .. so I figured it's better as seperate question. :)

So to recap: after a couple minor tweaks to the regexp provided by Chris (Thx!!) I managed to get it to pull the Package name (as well as optional BODY keyword .. so I know if it's header/body if both are in same script ) ..

Final parser is this:

```
     <parser id="plsql_func" 
              displayName="PL/SQL" 
              commentExpr="((/\*.*?\*)/|(--.*?$))">
         <function
             mainExpr="^[\w\s]{0,}(PACKAGE|FUNCTION|PROCEDURE)[\s]{1,}(BODY){0,1}[\s]{0,}[\w_.]{1,}">
             <functionName>
                 <nameExpr expr="^[\w\s]{0,}(PACKAGE|FUNCTION|PROCEDURE)[\s]{1,}\K(BODY){0,1}[\s]{0,}[\w_.]{1,}"/>
             </functionName>
         </function>
     </parser>
```

That works great .. however, results in something that looks like this:

[image]

Now for the tricky part (I'm fully expecting a response of "not possible" :) but figured it can't hurt to ask :) )

Is there any way to get that tree view expand/collapse option which is currently only on pk_test.sql ... have that on my pkg header/body records .. so like this:

[image]

I'm guessing that's asking for too much? :) 
(would be nice though .. hehe)

Comment: You might be able to do it using a classRange as specified here: https://notepad-plus-plus.org/features/function-list.html but after many attempts I can't seem to get it working

Comment: @Chrisrs2292  yeah, I see what you mean, fiddled a bit with it, but no luck .. oh well :) not that important .. was hoping perhaps something easy was there.  Thanks for trying to tackle it though!